# getting just column data from xlsx file with vue.js

Tags: excel, vue.js

I am able to read Excel file I need to read xls file col-wise, read data in every column and convert it to JSON.

How to read xls file col by col?

Getting trouble while fetching just first column data from xlsx file with vuejs

How to get particular column data from xlsx file with Vue js, anyone/?
i'm new to Vue js.
here, is the code that i used.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="err!==''">{{err}}</p>  <!-- Used to display errors -->
    
    <table v-if="content!==''">  <!-- Set center,Do not display if no content is obtained -->
      <!-- <tr>
        <th v-for="h in content[0]" :key="h.id">{{h}}</th>
      </tr>  Cycle read data and display -->
      
      <tr v-for="row in content.slice(0,)" :key=row.id>
        <td v-for="item in row" :key=item.id>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import XLSX from 'xlsx'

  export default {
    name: "App",
    data(){
    return {
      content: '',    //Initialization data
      err: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    var url = "/filw.csv"  //Files placed in the public directory can be accessed directly
    
    axios.get(url, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
    .then((res) => {
      var data = new Uint8Array(res.data)
      var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"})
      const firstSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0]
      const sheets = wb.Sheets[firstSheetName]
      // const results = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheets)
      // this.content = results
      this.content = this.getColumnData(sheets)
    }).catch( err =>{
      this.err = err
    })
  },
   methods: {
    getColumnData(sheet) {
      const ColData = []
      const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!refs'])
      let C
      const R = range.s.r
      /* start in the first row */
      for (C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) { /* walk every column in the range */
        const cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_col({ c: C, r: R })]
       
        ColData.push(cell)
      }
      return ColData
    }
  }
  
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

ANyone who know, help would be much appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data to json and then read the result, like this:

```
created() {
       var url = "/test.xlsx"  
       axios.get(url, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
       .then((res) => {
                        var data = new Uint8Array(res.data)
                        var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"})
                        const firstSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0]
                        const first_worksheet = wb.Sheets[firstSheetName]
                        // convert to json
                        const file_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(first_worksheet, { header: 1 });
                        // first column first row value
                        console.log(file_data[0][0])
                        })
       .catch( err =>{this.err = err})
},
```

Comment: This is almost "code only" answer. While code is useful, it is always better to explain in plain words what was changed and why...